# Discord bot 'interactionCreate' listener responded a few times, then quit responding without me changing the code

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

OS Windows 11

Versions:

- Node.js : v16.13.0
- npm : 8.1.0
- discord.js : ^13.7.0

Packages:

- "@discordjs/builders": "^0.13.0",
- "@discordjs/rest": "^0.4.1",
- "discord-api-types": "^0.32.1"

Scopes:

- applications.commands
- bot

Bot permission:

- administrator

I was following the tutorial [from the discord docs](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-handling.html#dynamically-executing-commands) and building slash commands for my bot. I was able to register the commands and get the success message, then /ping the bot and get a response. I committed and walked away. A few hours later I come back to start building more commands and the bot doesn't respond to /ping anymore. In fact, this block of code is not being reached at all:

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;
    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);
    if (!command) return;
    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
    }
});
```

I've tried:

- reinstall npm
- reinstall discord.js
- kick the bot and redo the scopes and permissions (not changing them)
- wait a few hours for the api to catch up registering the slash commands
- tried `interaction` instead of `interactionCreate`

Notes:

- I am using these intents : `FLAGS.GUILDS, FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, FLAGS.GUILD_EMOJIS_AND_STICKERS`
- I am using .mjs files for the commands, and `import()` syntax to register them. It was in a working state with those things when I left it. I've also tried reverting to `require` since the docs use that but that did not change anything.
- I did once get [the error described here](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/3498) but it went away and I now see `Successfully registered application commands` when I deploy the commands.
- UPDATE:

- The `require` syntax for importing files and registering events and commands seems to work. ES6 modules do not seem to let me register commands.